# upgrading 10 g to 11g checklist

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, upgrade

There are plenty of stored procedure on 10g platform . ( Almost 500 SPs)
Each SP might have loop, fetch and etc.

I'd like to ask you if there is a cool method to control all the SPs which are currently running on 10g, and guarantee that it works on 11 g.

I have a development server 1 which is 10 g and the other development server is 11 g.
I can use both of them to testify the propose above.

For instance I know that on 10 g if you use loop, and during the loop the update statements do not affect the loop data but 11g. 
There might be more cases that I have to consider. Please tell me if you have any brillant idea , otherwise I will check them up one by one manually and it is a lot of time and human control might be weak sometimes.

important note:   It is said that if you select some data from a table or tables, and if you use it in a loop, then during de loop, if you update and commit between loop case, it affects the selected data in cursor.(@11g) But this did not happen @10g version. Please correct me if you heard something like that.

The Example Case;

```
CREATE TABLE vty_musteri(
  musterino    NUMBER  NOT NULL,
  subeadi      VARCHAR2(61),
  kayitzamani  VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO vty_musteri (musterino, subeadi, kayitzamani )
  VALUES (12345, 'AMSTERDAM', '05/30/2012 15:11:13');
COMMIT;



CREATE UNIQUE INDEX vty_musteri_idx ON vty_musteri (musterino);

SELECT * FROM vty_musteri;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE krd_upd_silseomusteri_sp(RC1 in out  SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
  v_musterino NUMBER := 12345;

BEGIN

 OPEN RC1 FOR
    SELECT  m.musterino, m.subeadi, m.kayitzamani
      FROM vty_musteri m
     WHERE m.musterino = v_musterino;


   update vty_musteri
     set subeadi     = 'PORTO',
         kayitzamani = (SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                          FROM dual)
   where musterino = v_musterino;

  COMMIT;
```

**After all run this test on PLSQL:**

```
    DECLARE
       --test
       vRecTip   SYS_REFCURSOR;
       TYPE vRecTipK IS RECORD(
          musterino   NUMBER,
          subeadi     VARCHAR2(61),
          kayitzamani VARCHAR2(20)

          );
       v_SeoTip vRecTipK;
    BEGIN

       krd_upd_silseomusteri_sp(rc1 => vRecTip);

       IF vRecTip%ISOPEN THEN
          LOOP
             FETCH vRecTip
                INTO v_SeoTip;
             EXIT WHEN vRecTip%NOTFOUND;

             dbms_output.put_line('The Value : ' || v_SeoTip.musterino || ' - ' || v_SeoTip.subeadi || ' - ' || v_SeoTip.kayitzamani);

          END LOOP;
       END IF;
       COMMIT;
    END;   
END;
```

If you run this on 10g you will see AMSTERDAM, but on 11G, it is PORTO.

To fix it; I put a hint in the sp like the following:

```
  SELECT /*+ full(m)*/ m.musterino, m.subeadi, m.kayitzamani
```

Isn't it weird? any alternative sugesstion to get AMSTERDAM ?

Comment: you should really have a test suite for your application

Comment: If you post an example of a test case that behaves differently in 10g vs 11g, there may be something we can do to help.  It's not clear from your explanation what problem you're describing.

Comment: I put above. Please see the added notes.

Answer (score 2):

One thing we stumbled upon during a migration were queries that weren't supposed to work on 10.x (but did anyway) did no longer work on 11.x

This happens if you have ambigous column references in your query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT name,
       f.some_col,
       b.other_col
FROM foo f, 
  JOIN bar b ON f.id = b.fid
```

If the column `name` exists in both tables, 10.x would run the statement - which was a bug.

This bug (BugID: 6760937) was fixed and makes the statement (rightfully) fail in 11.x

Answer (score 1):

Basic PLSQL structures should work exactly the same. Some pitfalls are listed here:

http://www.help2ora.com/index.php/2011/08/04/be-careful-when-migrating-difference-between-oracle-10g-and-11g/

Comment: It is said that if you select some data from a table or tables, and if you use it in a loop, then during de loop, if you update and coomit between loop case, it affects the selected data in cursor.(@11g) But this did not happen @10g version. Please correct me if you heard something like that...

Answer (score 0):

> To fix it; I put a hint in the sp like the following:

SELECT /*+ full(m)*/ m.musterino, m.subeadi, m.kayitzamani

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have done migration to Oracle 11g. Faced few unprecedented issues. I have written a blog post on this. Have a look http://learncodewrite.blogspot.in/2017/04/migrating-to-oracle-11g-from-oracle-10g.html?m=1.